# How can I test that a variable is more than eight characters in PowerShell?

Tags: variables, testing, powershell

How do test if the number of characters in $dbUserName is more than eight characters?

I have been unable to locate a command or series of commands that will let me do this. I have only been able to find if the variable is null:

```
if ($dbUserName) {
    Write-Output " You left Username blank"
    $dbUserName = read-host
}
```

But I would like to next test like this:

```
if ($dbUserName [String] > 8 ) }
    Write-Output " Please enter more than 8 characters "
    $dbUserName=read-host " Re-enter database user name"
}
```

Comment: Odd, no one caught the logic in this code.  You're checking if the user name length is greater than 8, and upon True, you're asking them to enter more characters.  So, if the length is less than or equal to 8, it will be accepted.  I think it should be -lt or -le...

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Use the `length` property of the `[String]` type:

```
if ($dbUserName.length -gt 8) {
    Write-Output "Please enter more than 8 characters."
    $dbUserName = Read-Host "Re-enter database username"
}
```

Please note that you have to use `-gt` instead of `>` in your `if` condition. PowerShell uses the following *comparison operators* to compare values and test conditions:

- `-eq` = equals (`==`)
- `-ne` = not equals (`!=`)
- `-lt` = less than (`<`)
- `-gt` = greater than (`>`)
- `-le` = less than or equals (`<=`)
- `-ge` = greater than or equals (`>=`)

Comment: > is the redirection operator.  I suspect -gt might be a better choice.

Comment: @mjolinor Yes, that's correct. Perils of working with multiple languages. :)

Comment: Logic of this post is still flawed. If the username has a length MORE than 8 characters, the output is: enter more than 8 characters? It should be -lt

Comment: $var.length says that my string is 1 character, though it is near 30 actually.

Comment: What if our input is `[int]` and not `[string]`?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use -match against a Regular expression. Ex:

```
if ($dbUserName -match ".{8}" )
{
    Write-Output " Please enter more than 8 characters "
    $dbUserName=read-host " Re-enter database user name"
}
```

Also if you're like me and like your curly braces to be in the same horizontal position for your code blocks, you can put that on a new line, since it's expecting a code block it will look on next line. In some commands where the first curly brace has to be in-line with your command, you can use a grave accent marker (`) to tell powershell to treat the next line as a continuation.

Comment: Using a regular expression for such an easy task seems bound to be significantly slower.  Although in such a short operation it is probably not even noticeable though.

Comment: If you want to test for 8 or less the regex should be "^.{0,8}$". But I agree with @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo that this is (slightly) slower and more needlessly complex than it needs to be for a string length check.

Answer (score 0):

Works on Windows PowerShell v7.

You can also use the ternary operator ? as follows?

PS C:> `("Kipro".Length -gt 8) ? "True" : "False"`

Output: False

PS C:> `("Hello, how are you doing?".Length -gt 8) ? "True" : "False"`

Output: True

And of course, you can use check the condition of a variable holding a string as follows:

PS C:> $str1="Fort-Ternan"

PS C:> `($str1.Length -gt 8) ? "True" : "False"`

Output: True