# Is there a way to find the length of a string in Batch/PowerShell Script/VBScript?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, vbscript, computer-science

I need to find all phone numbers that I have ever stored on the computer. All of the phone numbers consist of eight numbers. Is there a way to search all of the text files on the computer for strings that are eight numbers in length and then print the location of these files, or simply copy these numbers?

I should be providing a code that I have tried, but I have not tried anything because I do not know where to start. I heard batch does not have such a function. What about the two other languages?

NOTE: Not looking for explanation of how to search for all of the files, that was merely an introduction. The main problem is finding the string length.

**Also, explaining why you are downvoting would be helpful for me.**

Comment: You could start by searching: **How to search all files?**

Comment: I know that part, dcg. Edited to make myself more clear.

Comment: *I should be providing a code that I have tried, but I have not tried anything because I do not know where to start.* - then you don't have an on-topic question for stack overflow... not being able to ask a good question doesn't make a bad question good. Googling "powershell string length" would surely get you further. Along with "powershell search files", "powershell search files for string", and similar.

Comment: So you can only ask questions if you partly know the answer? I tried googling, but since I am not good at coding, I could appreciate some people that can elaborate and that I can respond to, something that sites such as ss64 do not provide.

Comment: I went to Google and searched for the words "Powershell check string length" and the very first result was a link to stackoverflow answering your exact question. What you are not allowed to do is ask questions about things that you can easily solve on your own or have been solved before on this website.

Comment: The first stackoverflow result is not identical to my question, which includes three separate languages in the question and does not ask how to determine if a string is greater than 8 characters. Other than that, I'm sure nearly every question has a duplicate if you're going by that reasoning.

Comment: Surely you must know that google results are different for different users... This is the question I refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262403/how-can-i-test-that-a-variable-is-more-than-eight-characters-in-powershell). In your question you stated - "_Not looking for explanation of how to search for all of the files ... The main problem is finding the string length_" The first answer on that question shows exactly how to check string length. The second answer shows even another way to check string length. If checking string length is not the problem, edit your question.

Comment: Of course it doesn't completely answer your question; you're asking six different questions: checking string length in powershell, checking string length in batch, checking string length in vbscript, integer comparison in powershell, integer comparison in batch, and integer comparison in vbscript. And that's why your question was closed as "Too Broad."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findstr /m /R "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" *.txt
```

will list those files

see `findstr /?` from the prompt.

Comment: I will be testing that, thank you! Finally someone interested in helping.