# powershell how to set a character limit of no more than 15 characters, if more then prompt to re-enter the name

Tags: powershell, scripting

how do i go about setting a character limit for the following code?
would i need a IF statement here checking the length?

```
do { $VM = Read-Host "Enter Server Name" } 
until ($VM)
```

i have tried

```
do { [string][validatelength(0,15)] $VM = Read-Host "Enter Server Name" } 
until ($VM)
```

this is great if the input text is no more than 15... if its over it errors out
i need it to loop back so it asks for the correct name

how do i go about tweaking this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep looping until the input string satisfies your constraint:

```
do {
  $VM = Read-Host "Enter Server Name"
} while($VM.Length -gt 15)
```

Comment: that doesnt seem to work... when i entered in a name thats 16 characters it spat out this error The variable cannot be validated because the value 1234567890123456 is not a valid value for the VM variable.
entering a value of 15 characters it was ok.
entering a blank value was also accepted but blank values arent meant to be allowed, its meant to loop that as well so something is entered in

Comment: @RogerDingo That's probably because you're running my code in the same shell as your previous attempts, in which `$VM` has had the `[ValidateLength(0,15)]` constraint set. Test in a fresh instance of PowerShell or run `Remove-Variable VM -Force` before testing again

Comment: ah yes youre right... clearing the variable fixed it. entering a name thats 16 characters loops back and asks for a name.
how do i cater for a blank value and getting that to loop back to the same input question?

Comment: By testing for it in the condition: `while($VM.Length -gt 15 -or $VM.Length -lt 1)`. Or perhaps `while($VM.Length -notin 1..15)`

Comment: argghh... i put the OR switch in but forgot to add the minus character in front!... lets try that out...

Comment: amazing.. that seems to be working as expected... thank you so much!
is there any benefit in using the  -notin or using a -or in your while expression?

Comment: The "benefit" is whether it's easy to read and reason about for the next person who has to read/understand your code, use your best judgment :)

Comment: ok makes sense... personally for me... using the -or statement with -lt 1 and -gt15 makes a lot more sense, easier to read 
thanks again for your help!

Comment: @RogerDingo If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "acccepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :

```
$VM = "anything over 15"

while ($VM -match ".{15}" ){
$VM = Read-Host "Enter Server Name"
}
```

I found info about checking length in this post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262403/how-can-i-test-that-a-variable-is-more-than-eight-characters-in-powershell)

And [here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_while?view=powershell-7.2) microsoft's documentation about while loops.

Answer (score 0):

even an if condition will work.

```
$VM = "qwertyuiop"

if ($VM.length -gt 15) {
    Write-Output "Please enter more than 15 characters."
    $VM = Read-Host "Re-enter VM Name"
}

$VM
```